# How to calculate the transfer function of an RLC circuit?

Tags: passive-networks

I'm starting to study control systems, but I'm still having difficulty with the modeling issue to obtain the transfer function.

The input voltage is on the signal generator (VE) and the output voltage is on the capacitor (VS)

[image]
[image]

Based on this RLC circuit. Could anyone help me get the transfer function?
​The inductor is a coil of open transformer (the inductance is in the order of mH).

Comment: Sure. What is the difficulty and what help you need to get the transfer function?

Comment: Thanks, for your willingness to help. My difficulty lies in properly modeling the RLC circuit with an open transformer coil. I'm unsure about how to incorporate the open transformer coil into the circuit model and how it affects the overall behavior of the system. Specifically, I'm not sure how to represent the inductor in the circuit given that it's a coil of an open transformer, especially considering that the inductance is in the order of millihenries. Any guidance on how to properly model this aspect of the circuit and subsequently derive the transfer function would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You have drawn a 20mH inductor so you model it as a 20mH inductor. If it is not an 20mH inductor then it is something else and you should edit your question what it is.

Comment: Are you actually wanting to mathematically derive the TF or just use your simulator. It's not that clear.

Comment: "Specifically, I'm not sure how to represent the inductor in the circuit given that it's a coil of an open transformer, ":  If this is what is being asked, then it is not consistent with the title of the question. Please edit the question to clarify.

Comment: A circuit does not have a single transfer function (TF). Since a TF is a ratio between an output voltage to an input voltage, then the these voltages must be specified. Please edit the question indicating the output and input voltages involved.

Answer (score 1):

The transfer of this second-order system can easily be derived without writing a line of algebra using the fast analytical circuits techniques or FACTs. You have to determine the time constants of the system when the excitation is turned off (the ac source is replaced by a short) then find high-frequency gains when each energy-storing element is alternatively set in its open- or short-circuited state. A few sketches and you are done:

[image]

So you have one zero and a 2nd-order polynomial in the denominator which is characterized by a quality factor and a resonant frequency. The plot is shown below:

[image]

Comment: Nice! If you could clarify a few things for me, like explaining a bit about the process you did in the circuit figures, and the variable names? in the reference books I'm using, do you use the transfer function G(s), in which case it would be Href(s)? Because I need to get the modulus and phase of G(s), I saw that these are functions of approximations that can help in the analysis of systems, using the low and high frequencies. As well as the pass band

Comment: What would the experimental lag curve look like if the parasitic resistance of the inductor, Rs, were zero? Could a filter be applied to the circuit?

Comment: I am using the fast analytical circuits techniques or FACTs that I described in my last [book](https://stairwaypress.com/product/fast-track/). It consists of identifying time constants of a circuit - passive or active - associated with energy-storing elements (capacitors and inductors).

Answer (score 0):

Well, your transfer function is given by:

$$\mathscr{H}\left(\text{s}\right):=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{o}\left(\text{s}\right)}{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{i}\left(\text{s}\right)}=\frac{\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{sC}}\space\text{||}\space\left(\text{R}_\text{s}+\text{sL}\right)}{\displaystyle\text{R}+\left(\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{sC}}\space\text{||}\space\left(\text{R}_\text{s}+\text{sL}\right)\right)}=\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_\text{s}+\text{sL}}{\displaystyle\text{R}+\text{R}_\text{s}+\text{s}\left(\text{L}+\text{CR}\left(\text{R}_\text{s}+\text{sL}\right)\right)}\tag1$$

Where \$\displaystyle\alpha\space\text{||}\space\beta:=\frac{\displaystyle\alpha\beta}{\displaystyle\alpha+\beta}\$.